# Is there any research on how to use the "put yourself in the other person's shoes" method effectively?

Tags: decision-making, empathy

I recently read "How to win friends and influence people" by Dale Carnegie. One important piece of advice in the book was the ability to understand the other person's perspective. For example, in business and personal relations.

It's definitely a useful thing to do when making decisions, but I've realized that you can also use it wrong. For example, thinking about the other person's perspective for 2 hours might make you feel good and like you understand the other person; but humans are complex, you can't get into their head. You cannot understand the other person's perspective completely.

Are there any resources on this topic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Learn Cognitive Empathy](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/27553/7001) and [From a neuroscientific standpoint, what are the most effective ways to develop empathy, love and compassion for others?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/19375/7001)